# Angular-CLI proxy to backend still doesn't work for some reason

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli, running project from localhost:4200 and trying to get server request from myurl:8080. This isn't working for some reason, have tried all the options but none helped.

Here is my **proxy.config.json** file:

```
{
  "/myservice/*": {
    "target": "http://myurl:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/myservice" : ""}
  }
}
```

A simple **http.get** :

```
  private Url = 'http://myurl:8080/myservice/list/getlist';

  headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
  options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true});

  getList (): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.Url, this.options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The **browser result** is:

> 403 (Forbidden). Response to preflight request doesn't pass access
>   control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

If I just surf to http://myurl:8080/myservice/list/getlist I will get the JSON result. Did any one made it worked?

after `npm start` **@Angular/cli** is writing

```
Proxy created: /myservice -> http://myurl:8080
[HPM] Proy rewrite rule create "^/myservice" ~"
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events: ['error', 'close']
```

Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to call from localhost the full backend url. If you want the "changeOrigin" proxy option to make apply you have to try to call the backend like this:

http://localhost:4200/myservice this will point to -> http://backendUrl:8080/myservice 
and server will see as origin the backendurl.

if we want to emit the myservice from the backendurl then path rewrite proxy option is "pathRewrite": {"^/myservice" : ""}

SO try to call backend using the localhost:4200/myservice
and set the proxy configs like this:

```
{
  "/myservice/*": {
    "target": "http://myurl:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
  }
}
```

TIP: For more advanced options, as the angular-cli serve use webpack-dev-server which also use the http-proxy-middleware which also use the http-proxy you may also apply their options to the proxy.conf.js file. 
https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options

e.x cookieRewrite

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/myservice"
    ],
    target: "http://backendurl",
    secure: false,
    logLevel: "debug",
    changeOrigin: true,
    cookieDomainRewrite: {
      "backendurl": ""
    }
  }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi i got the same problem, have you check that you start with 'ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json' ? If yes try a 'catch all proxyconfig' like this:

```
{
  "**": {
  "target": "http://myurl:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": false,
  "logLevel": "debug"
  }}
```

with this you can test if any request goes to your backendserver.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but your method does not work. Maybe you have any ideas?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872498/configure-angular-cli-proxy-for-custom-headers-in-request-to-backend

Thanks